# Watir-webdriver can't see an input tag inside a popup

Tags: css, ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

I keep getting `Element is not currently visible and cannot be interacted with` after a javascript successfully pops up a dialogue div that contains some  tags.

I can locate the input tags whichever way I want but I can't set them to anything because they're not visible, even though they clearly are.

I've tried running a `.execute_script` which changes the CSS style of the input tags to `position:absolute` or `z-index:999` or `display:block` but it doesn't seem to matter.

Is there a way to force an element to be visible while using watir-webdriver?

Been banging my head against the wall for hours, would really appreciate some help.

PS. the buttons inside of a popup are nice and clickable, the inputs are not :(

Comment: Please provide link to the page where we can reproduce the problem. Or post relevant HTML if the page is not public. Of course, your Watir code too.

Comment: What are the current properties of the elements? (position type, coordinates, z-index, and display would be the most interesting ones) 

Can you show us the code for the inputs?  if they are not standard HTML inputs but are implemented via CSS or Javascript, then you might need to be firing some specific events at them in order to get them to react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the guys who pitched in. Problem ended up being an outlying div I forgot to check for opacity attributes.

Comment: You should accept this as an answer then.  And thanks for getting back to us and sharing the solution, could be very beneficial for someone else who runs into the same issue.